# Matrix pencil with determinant equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-pencil

Let $\sum_{i=1}^n x_k \hat M_k\equiv \hat M(\vec x)$ be a $n\times n$ matrix pencil such that $\det \hat M(\vec x)=0$ for every $\vec x$. Let us also assume that for every vector $\vec y$, there is a vector $\vec x$ such that $\hat M(\vec x)\vec y=0$. An obvious way for satisfying these conditions is to choose general matrices for $\hat M_k$ such that their images are equal to a given $(n-1)$-dimensional vector space. In other words, this means that there is a vector $\vec z\ne\vec 0$ such that $\hat M_k^T \vec z=0$ for every $k=1,\dots,n$. Is this constraint necessary?

A weaker condition is that there is a basis $\vec y_1,\dots,\vec y_n$ such that there are vectors $\vec x_k$ with $\hat M(\vec x_k)\vec y_k=0$ for every $k=1\dots n$.

Comment: even if all matrices have a common vector in their null spaces, how does this prove that for every $y$ there is a $M(x)$ such that $M(x)y=0$?

Comment: Well, if the matrices are general with this constraint, you should have the other condition satisfied.

Comment: The condition should probably be "for every vector $\vec{y}$ there is a *nonzero* vector $\vec{x}$ such that $\hat{M}(\vec{x})\vec{y} = 0$", otherwise we can always take $\vec{x} = 0$.

Comment: Yes, that’s right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider the pencil $\begin{bmatrix}0 & x_1 & x_2 \\ -x_1 & 0 & x_3 \\ -x_2 & -x_3 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ generating all alternating $3 \times 3$ matrices.

The determinant is $0$ (every alternating matrix has rank $2$). For every $\vec{y} = (y_1, y_2, y_3)^\top$ it is easy to find a matrix $\hat{M}(\vec{x})$ with $\vec{y}$ in the kernel, namely $\begin{bmatrix}0 & y_3 & 
 - y_2 \\ - y_3 & 0 & y_1 \\ y_2 & -y_1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ for $\vec{y} \neq 0$.

But the common kernel of all alternating matrices is trivial, so we have a counterexample.

Comment: You are right. I have just a concern. In the original problem, I had an extra-condition that I didn’t mention in the question, as I thought that it was unnecessary to prove the conclusion. I think that the conclusion is correct with this additional condition, but I don’t have a clear proof. Is it fine for you if I add it as P.S. and I don’t mark your answer as the accepted one for the moment? I am aware that it would be unfair to change the question after a right answer. Otherwise, I will ask another question with modified statement.

Comment: I think the site rules say it's better to ask another question. I realized that there is an even simpler counterexample $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. The additional restrictions must be quite strong to rule out this, I think.

Comment: This is not a counterexample.

Comment: Right, sorry, I missed the transpose there in the question. Anyway, we can discuss modifications in another questions.